# Problems with Flutter InAppWebView (Blank Page)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

When clicking on the links on the site whatsapp.com blank pages open.
The URL in "onLoadStart" returns an empty string. No errors in "onLoadError".
If paste the URL into "initialUrlRequest", then everything works fine.
If disable JavaScript, then everything works fine too. This problem is only with JavaScript enabled.
if open the site and click link in a regular browser, then everything is fine
Thank you for your help!

flutter_inappwebview
5.3.2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.